# Which is more secure OFB or CFB?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, openssl, aes

I'm working a small project, using AES encryption and wanted to use it in streaming mode, which is considered a more "suitable" mode for socket usage? OFB or CFB?
I've been reading about it and can't really decide, so any ideas are highly appreciated.

I'll be using OpenSSL/C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both OFB and CFB are solid if unexciting [cipher modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_mode) (compared with, say, '[Infinite Garble Extension](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/workshop1/presentations/slides-knudsen-modesp.pdf)', IGE, which at least sounds more exciting) - either will serve you well.  Choose one and stick with it.  And, if [Bruce Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html)'s blog is correct, use AES-128 (rather than either AES-192 or AES-256).